# Form Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking to set up a form that will have a progress bar, while the user fills out the input fields. I have set up everything I know from the tutorials and online, but its not working.

Please look over if anyone can figure out why its not working.

its saved here - > http://jsfiddle.net/VbP4w/

This is sample JS code

```
      $("#form input").keyup(function() {
      var numValid = 0;
      $("#form input[required]").each(function() {
          if (this.validity.valid) {
              numValid++;
          }
      });

      var progress = $("#progress"),
          progressMessage = $("#message");

      if (numValid == 0) {
          progress.attr("value", "0");
          progressMessage.text("Please Enter Student ID.");
      }
      if (numValid == 1) {
          progress.attr("value", "10");
          progressMessage.text("Please Enter the First Name.");
      }
      if (numValid == 2) {
          progress.attr("value", "20");
          progressMessage.text("Please Enter the Last Name.");
      }
      if (numValid == 3) {
          progress.attr("value", "30");
          progressMessage.text("Please Enter Your E-mail");
      }
      if (numValid == 4) {
          progress.attr("value", "40");
          progressMessage.text("Please Enter a Password.");
      }
      if (numValid == 5) {
          progress.attr("value", "50");
          progressMessage.text("Please Re-Enter a Password.");
      }
      if (numValid == 6) {
          progress.attr("value", "60");
          progressMessage.text("Please Enter A Street Address.");
      }
      if (numValid == 7) {
          progress.attr("value", "70");
          progressMessage.text("Please Enter a City.");
      }
      if (numValid == 8) {
          progress.attr("value", "80");
          progressMessage.text("Please Enter a ZipCode.");
      }
      if (numValid == 9) {
          progress.attr("value", "100");
          progressMessage.text("Please Pick a State and Submit the Form.");
      }

      });
```

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery library http://jsfiddle.net/VbP4w/2/

Comment: in that case, how would I implement this in HTML? @asprin

Comment: Put this `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` inside your `<head>` section or right before `$("#form input").keyup(function() {`

Comment: @asprin that didint really work, maybe wrong library?

Comment: just include the jquery libray, like asprin said. [http://jsfiddle.net/7PbGT/](http://jsfiddle.net/7PbGT/)

Comment: The jsfiddle works when jQuery is selected there. If the code “does not work” when jQuery is included, then the problem is apparently somewhere else, not in the code included in the question.

Comment: That's strange. If you're using the exact same code as shown in the jsfiddle, it should have worked. Could you show me where exactly did you place the library?

Comment: @asprin i placed the link to library in the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script‌​>
<script>
$(function(){ // do not forget to add this too
$("#form input").keyup(function() {
          var numValid = 0;
          $("#form input[required]").each(function() {
              if (this.validity.valid) {
                  numValid++;
              }
          });
.
.
.
.
.
.
});
}); // and the closing braces
</script>
```

PS: Note the two different `<script>` tags. They need to be separate. Also put do not forget to wrap your `keyup` function inside `$(function(){});`

Comment: @aspirin, thats exactly how i have it set up.. one on top of each other,in their own tags... no running through the browser tho.. you can try it here.. http://web.njit.edu/~tv37/202/home.html

Comment: It's definitely because of not wrapping your keyup function inside `$(function(){})`

Comment: perfect. all because of the brackets